# Запуск тестов Selenium с Xvfb выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Всем привет! Вопрос в следующем про Xvfb + Selenium WD + Python.
1. Есть сервер на котором крутятся тесты (CentOS + Jenkins)
2. Запуск тестов происходит без графики, используем Xvfb.

Ситуация такая что тесты нормально идут вплоть до команды:

```
    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://myURL.com','_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('username')
```

После чего падают с ошибкой:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('name')
<...>
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
```

В целом свидетельствующей о том, что элемент не был найден и тест упал по таймауту. Это крайне странно учитывая, что локально, на моей машине тесты проходят идеально.
Кейс такой:

1. Найти элемент на странице - кликунуть по нему.
2. Подождать пока появится другой элемент.
3. Открыть новую вкладку (с другим url) и ввести там логин/пароль (авторизоваться). <- *тут как раз и ошибка*

Такое ощущение, что Xvfb не может нормально работать со второй вкладкой браузера. Сразу ещё отмечу, что пробовал ставить разные задержки - `time.sleep(5), wait.until(...), implicitly_wait(...)` не помогло.

Comment: Дебажьте, делайте скриншоты перед таймаутом, смотрите DOM и консоль ошибок браузера, запущенного внутри Xvfb

Comment: А как делается импорт, можно строчку с импортом?

Comment: чего именно импорт можете уточнить?